# How to drupal_add_js an external and defer script

Tags: 7, javascript

I've spent quite some time on [`drupal_add_js`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x) and didn't manage to solve this. How can I load an external JavaScript script which will also have the `defer` attribute?

I want to use this type of syntax:

```
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/whatever.js', 'external');
```

But it only produces:

```
<script src="http://example.com/whatever.js"></script>
```

I want the end HTML to be:

```
<script defer="defer" src="http://example.com/whatever.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following syntax:

```
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/whatever.js', array('type' => 'external', 'defer' => 'defer'));
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add a value in `$options`

```php
$options = array(
  'type' => 'external',
  'defer' => TRUE,
);
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/whatever.js', $options);
```

From the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x):

> **Parameters**
>
> **$options**: (optional) A string defining the type of JavaScript that is being added in the $data parameter ('file'/'setting'/'inline'/'external'), or an associative array. JavaScript settings should always pass the string 'setting' only. Other types can have the following elements in the array:
>
> - **type**: The type of JavaScript that is to be added to the page. Allowed values are 'file', 'inline', 'external' or 'setting'. Defaults to 'file'.
> - ...
> - **defer**: If set to TRUE, the defer attribute is set on the  tag. Defaults to FALSE.

Comment: Good answer, found it interesting the drupal 7 still doesn't support async attribute, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1664602

Comment: @powpow12 Drupal 7 is fading out so no one focusing on any new feature....

Comment: Covid19 blew the door open with how long d7 will be around till, right now slated for [11/28/2022](https://www.drupal.org/docs/understanding-drupal/drupal-9-release-date-and-what-it-means/what-happens-to-drupal-7-now-that#:~:text=Drupal%207%20community%20support%20is%20provided%20until%20November%202022,-In%20the%20past&text=Now%2C%20in%20light%20of%20the,%2Dlife%20in%20November%202021).