# How to add a custom attribute to the script tag via drupal_add_js?

Tags: 7, javascript

As part of API implementation of Queue-it framework, I need to add extra custom attribute `data-queueit-c` into `script` tag, e.g.

```
<script 
    data-queueit-c="MyClientID" 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="//static.queue-it.net/script/queueconfigloader.min.js">
</script>
```

I'm aware you can add other [attributes such as `defer`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/210976/1908), however this one is custom.

I've tried the following code using [`drupal_add_js`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x), but without luck:

```
drupal_add_js('//static.queue-it.net/script/queueconfigloader.min.js',
  [ 
    'type' => 'external',
    'data-queueit-c' => 'MyClientID',
  ]);
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

It's old but I have the same problem (adding "crossorigin" attribute) and this is my answer :

- There is an issue about it here : https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1664602
- @kenorb solution can't work because "drupal_add_js" add "script" tag automatically.
  But... you can try this workaround (a little dirty) :
  close the script tag and open yours without closing

.

```
drupal_add_js('//--><!]]></script><script src="//static.queue-it.net/script/queueconfigloader.min.js" data-queueit-c="MyClientID"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--', 'inline');
```

Answer (score -1):

As for workaround, inline syntax can be used, e.g.

```
$js_code = "<script data-queueit-c='MyClientID' type='text/javascript' src='//static.queue-it.net/script/queueconfigloader.min.js'></script>";
drupal_add_js($js_code, 'inline');
```

Comment: The alternative looks like a real pain. `drupal_get_js` is very selective about what attributes it will use, so you'd need to re-implement that whole function and at the same time convince the system to use your new version instead. Not worth the hassle IMO

Comment: This does not seem to work, here is what i get : 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
<script data-queueit-c='MyClientID' type='text/javascript' src='//static.queue-it.net/script/queueconfigloader.min.js'></script>
//--><!]]>
</script>

Comment: @Thony This solution is for Drupal 7, maybe you're using 8.

Comment: No I am using 7