# Add js with custom type

Tags: javascript

How can i add a script file with `type='module'`, like this :

```
<script src="site/test/test/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

I tried with :

```
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/assets/js/my_script.js', [
    'attributes' => ['type' => 'module'],
    'type' => 'module',
  ]);
```

But Drupal 7 only accept 'file', 'inline', 'external' or 'setting' as type.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot, for the reason you said. What would you expect to happen, when the type is *module*?

Comment: Hello, i want to insert a ReactJs script and i need to set the type at module to import a dependencie in my script.

Comment: Just use one of the values the function accepts basing on the script being used. Drupal doesn't recognize a ReactJS module as script type.

Comment: This one can help you [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253634/how-to-add-a-custom-attribute-to-the-script-tag-via-drupal-add-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in hook_preprocess_html():

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$var) {
  $script = [
    '#tag' => 'script',
    '#attributes' => [
      'type' => 'module',
      'src' => 'path/to/script.js',
    ],
    '#value' => '',
  ];
  drupal_add_html_head($script, 'script');  
}
```